# Show that $B' = \{v_1+v, v_2+v,\ldots, v_n+v\}$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if $v \ne \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = -1$ as follow

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $B = \{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ be a basis of a vector space $V$ and let $v \in V$.
Show that $B' = \{v_1+v, v_2+v,\ldots, v_n+v\}$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if
$v \ne \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = -1$.

Here's what I tried:

For right direction, assume that $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ for some $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = -1$.
Since $B'$ is a basis, then the equation
$a_1(v_1+v) + a_2(v_2+v) + \ldots + a_n(v_n+v) = 0$ satisfied only by $a_i=0$ for all $i$.
But, $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = -1$, a contradiction. Hence, $v \ne \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ where
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = -1$.

For the left direction, I have no idea to start since I only given:
$v \ne \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = -1$ and to show $B'$ linearly independent,
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(v_i+v) = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + \ldots + a_nv_n + v(a_1+a_2 + \ldots + a_n) 
\ne v - v = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $B'$ is not a basis of $V$. Then, there are constants $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$, not all zero, such that $$\lambda_1(v_1+v)+\lambda_2(v_2+v)+\ldots+\lambda_n(v_n+v)=0\tag{1}$$.

Notice that the coefficient before $v$ in the left-hand side of (1) is $s=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\ldots+\lambda_n$, so that

$$\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\ldots+\lambda_nv_n=-sv\tag{2}$$

If $s=0$, then (2) becomes $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\ldots+\lambda_nv_n=0$, contradicting the assumption that $B$ is a basis. So $s\neq 0$. Then (2) can be rewritten as

$$
\bigg(\frac{-\lambda_1}{s}\bigg)v_1+\bigg(\frac{-\lambda_2}{s}\bigg)v_2+\ldots+\bigg(\frac{-\lambda_n}{s}\bigg)v_n = v \tag{3}
$$

Putting $a_k=\frac{-\lambda_k}{s}$ for $1\leq k\leq n$, we then have $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=-1$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: This is the right or left direction Sir ?

Comment: This is the proof by contrapositive, right? And, how about my right direction proof, Sir?

Comment: Yes, it's a proof by contrapositive. Your right direction proof looks ok to me.

Comment: Okay sir, thanks for your help!